# Pointfree topology via Convergence

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, lattice-orders

Simply put:

> Is there a useful version of pointfree [convergence spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convergence+space)? If yes, what are resources dealing with this?

This seems like an obvious thing to ask, since there is a pointfree version of topology (I mean locales, not the mathematical area of "topology").

---

One objection that comes to mind is, that the definition very explicitely mentions points. 
I can think of a way to eliminate this problem: replace $x$ with its principal ultrafilter $\{A : x\in A\}$. So one possible approach to create a pointfree definition is to start with a poset $(P,\leq)$ with elements thought of as "filters" with a reflexive relation $\to $ on $P$, such that analogous versions of the other axioms of a convergence space hold. But this is just one idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03226), a pointfree version of convergence spaces is introduced.